# htaccess https to http redirect - simply for all urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

My programmer wrote me this (see below) for my htaccess file to redirect all requests for https to http. I have a SSL but I am not using it on any files at the moment so I just need to simply redirect all https's to the http version. It is now working but only for my homepage.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Is this correct ? Or do I need to add something?

Answer (score 1):

The code you were given is correct, but you have to enable the rewriting engine before usage. Also the usage of `.htaccess` style files has to be activated inside the main server configuration. Please see the excellent [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) about that topic.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Apart from this a general hint: *if* you have access to the main server configuration (to enable such use), then it makes sense to place such rules right inside the host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Such files are notoriously error prone, make things complex, are hard to debug and really slow the server down.